# Rails Association Chains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two models, `Circuit` and `Organisation` with the following relationship:

**circuit.rb**

```
belongs_to :organisation
```

**organisation.rb**

```
has_many :circuits
```

**circuit_controller.rb**

```
...
if params[:id]
  @circuit = Circuit.find(params[:id])
  @backup_circuits = @circuit.organisation.circuits.where('id != ?', @circuit.id)
end
...
```

**update.rhtml (Circuit View)**

```
<%= collection_select 'circuit', 'backup_circuit_id', @backup_circuits, :id, :product_name %>
```

but I get this error: `undefined method`product_name' for " # AND id != ?  ":String`

As far as I can see the modelling should be fine, the only thing I'm doubtful about is the chaining I have done in the controller as it seems a bit funny to find the `circuit`, it's `organisation` and then other `circuits` belonging to that `organisation`.

Rails verions is 2.3.14

Alternatively, if I use

```
<%= select "circuit", "backup_circuit_id", @backup_circuits %>
```

instead then I the page renders but my dropdown values are empty and the values are the hex address you get when you know something is broken...

Comment: I guess you passed extra argument for `collection_select` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select). Could you try to remove `'circuit'` from it?

Comment: if I do that I get `wrong number of arguments (4 for 5)` but I would need it as that's the object all my form post data will be stored in.

Comment: Try to call `#all` on `@backup_circuits`. Looks like it doesn't like to have a relation passed instead of an array. Like `@backup_circuits.all` or `@backup_circuits = @circuit.organisation.circuits.where('id != ?', @circuit.id).all`

Comment: If I try that I then get `undefined method `all' for #<Array:0x11041dac8>`

Comment: Are you sure that Rails 2.3.14 supports the `.where()` method? Try `@circuit.organisation.circuits.find(:all, :conditions => ['id != ?', @circuit.id])`

Comment: ah, you are right again @MrYoshiji, if you post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Rails 2.3.14 supports the `.where()` - Actually it does not for Rails 2.3.11, just tried it.

In Rails 2.3.14, you can't really chain the queries... Here is the Rails 2.3.x solution:

```
@circuit.organisation.circuits.find(:all, :conditions => ['id != ?', @circuit.id])
```